# Unable to receive proper data from the promise function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, cheerio, request-promise

I am trying to scrap wikipedia page to fetch list of airlines by first scrapping first page and then going to each individual page of airline to get the website url. I have divided the code in two functions. One to scrap main page and get a new url, and second function to scrap another page from the created url to get the website name from that page. I have used request-promise module for getting the html and then cheerio to parse the data.

```
export async function getAirlinesWebsites(req,res) {

let response = await request(options_mainpage);
console.log(`Data`);

let $ = cheerio.load(response);
console.log('Response got');

 $('tr').each((i,e)=>{
     let children = '';
    console.log('inside function ', i);
        if($(e).children('td').children('a').attr('class') !== 'new') {
            children = $(e).children('td').children('a').attr('href');


            let wiki_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org' + children;
            console.log(`wiki_url = ${wiki_url}`);

             let airline_url = getAirlineUrl(wiki_url);
             console.log(`airline_url = ${airline_url}`);
        }
})
```

And then the getAirlineUrl() function will parse another page based on the provided url.

```
async function getAirlineUrl(url){

    const wiki_child_options = {
        url : url,
        headers : headers
    }


   let child_response = await request(wiki_child_options);
        let $ = cheerio.load(child_response);

        let answer = $('.infobox.vcard').children('tbody').children('tr').children('td').children('span.url').text();

        return answer;

    })
```

However when I console log the answer variable in the parent function, I get a [object Promise] value instead of a String. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: airline_url returns object promise?

Comment: yes it gives  [object Promise] when I console log it.

Comment: My guess is you're trying to set the `span.url`'s content with a request somewhere else in the code, but requests are asynchronous and this one is returning a promise, so wherever you're setting the `span.url`'s text, do it in a successful promise callback, don't set it to the promise's value. [MDN Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), expanding on what I mean by setting to the promise it looks like `$(..).text(someReq()); function someReq() { ... return promise; }`

Comment: @PatrickBarr span.url is just a text containing a url which is being passed to another function to parse that page.

Answer (score 1):

Async function return promise.In case of that,you need to use then to get resolved response or use await. 
This should work if other part of your code is ok.

```
export async function getAirlinesWebsites(req, res) {
  let response = await request(options_mainpage);
  console.log(`Data`);

  let $ = cheerio.load(response);
  console.log("Response got");

  $("tr").each(async (i, e) => {
   let children = "";
   console.log("inside function ", i);
   if ($(e).children("td").children("a").attr("class") !== "new") {
     children = $(e).children("td").children("a").attr("href");

     let wiki_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org" + children;
     console.log(`wiki_url = ${wiki_url}`);

     let airline_url = await getAirlineUrl(wiki_url);
     console.log(`airline_url = ${airline_url}`);
   }
 });
}
```

Comment: For anyone who can't tell, the spotted differences are the addition of `async` to the arrow function within `$("tr").each(...)` and `await` in front of `getAirlineUrl(wiki_url);`

Comment: It is returning Unhandled promise rejection error now

Comment: Use try..catch inside async function to catch the error.

Comment: With this approach, `getAirlinesWebsites ` will evaluate and resolve its promise before the `getAirlineUrl` functions finish.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `getAirlineUrl` function returns a promise, you need to `await` that promise. You can't have `await` nested inside of the `.each` callback because the callback is not an async function, and if it was it wouldn't work still. The best fix is the avoid using `.each` and just use a loop.

```
export async function getAirlinesWebsites(req,res) {

  let response = await request(options_mainpage);
  console.log(`Data`);

  let $ = cheerio.load(response);
  console.log('Response got');

  for (const [i, e] of Array.from($('tr')).entries()) {
    let children = '';
    console.log('inside function ', i);
    if($(e).children('td').children('a').attr('class') !== 'new') {
      children = $(e).children('td').children('a').attr('href');


      let wiki_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org' + children;
      console.log(`wiki_url = ${wiki_url}`);

      let airline_url = await getAirlineUrl(wiki_url);
      console.log(`airline_url = ${airline_url}`);
    }
  }
}
```